# How to implement Addthis Sharing button In Angular 4?

Tags: angular, addthis

I Have problem to load Add this button load issue, when i am on product page and Refresh or CTRL+f5 page on product page then Shared button showing, But come on product page from another page or some another links then its was not showing. please help me how to use that or what's solution for that.

In Index.html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid={MyId}"></script>
```

and In i want to use in Product.html page then i was write that below code

```
    <div 
  class="addthis_inline_share_toolbox"  
  [attr.data-title]="ProductDetails?.ProductTitle" 
  [attr.data-image]="ProductDetails?.PhotoFileName[0]"
  [attr.data-description]="ProductDetails?.ProductDescritpion" >
</div>
```

Comment: Perhaps create a component for add this, then you include it on each component/page where you want it. e.g. <addThis></addThis>.

Comment: create component then use it. but it's not showing, same problem. and now its not load on ctrl+f5

Comment: Without knowing the structure of your application, help may be hard. Perhaps watch the network traffic to s7.addthis.com. Could be it is not loading in time the first time? (just a guess)

Comment: Hi Urvish i am even not able to show inline on particular component. Can u pls help me to show inline share tool on particular component html page ?